# How do I make these function definitions D.R.Y.?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, hadoop, parquet

I have multiple function definitions to write a parquet file, but I'd rather have one general function. How can I make one general function work? The problem is that one general function returns error
`could not find implicit value for parameter writerFactory: com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetWriter.ParquetWriterFactory[Product]`

Multiple functions:

```scala
import com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetWriter
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

def writeParquetUnsegmented(rows: List[ACaseClass], date: String) = {
    val outPath = s"s3a://redacted/path-$date.parquet"
    ParquetWriter.writeAndClose(outPath,
                                rows,
                                    ParquetWriter.Options(
                                                        writeMode = ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE,
                                                        compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY
                                                        ))
}

def writeParquetSegmented(rows: List[BCaseClass], date: String) = {
    val outPath = s"s3a://redacted/path-$date.parquet"
    ParquetWriter.writeAndClose(outPath,
                                rows,
                                    ParquetWriter.Options(
                                                        writeMode = ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE,
                                                        compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY
                                                        ))
}
```

One function:

```
def writeParquetSegmented(rows: List[Product], date: String) = {
    val outPath = s"s3a://redacted/path-$date.parquet"
    ParquetWriter.writeAndClose(outPath,
                                rows,
                                    ParquetWriter.Options(
                                                        writeMode = ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE,
                                                        compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY
                                                        ))
}
```

I have also tried different function signatures and got the same error.

```scala
def writeParquetSegmented[A](rows: List[A], date: String)
```

```scala
def writeParquetSegmented[A :< RowParent](rows: List[A], date: String)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this signature:

```scala
def writeParquetSegmented[A : ParquetWriterFactory](rows: List[A], date: String)
```

The compiler will turn the [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html) `[A : ParquetWriterFactory]` into an implicit parameter that the error message complains about.

```scala
def writeParquetSegmented[A](rows: List[A], date: String)(implicit pwf: ParquetWriterFactory)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think to add `(implicit pwf: ParquetWriterFactory[A])`

Answer (score 2):

Just make the function generic:

```scala
def writeParquetUnsegmented[A](
  rows: List[A],
  date: String)(
  implicit writerFactory: ParquetWriterFactory[A]) = {
    val outPath = s"s3a://redacted/path-$date.parquet"
    ParquetWriter.writeAndClose(
      outPath,
      rows,
      ParquetWriter.Options(
        writeMode = ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE,
        compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY))
}
```